# Create Excel with Java format text

Tags: java, excel

When I download Excel, I get cells with format Numbers I need format text en all Cells.

```
try {
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(eyelash);

            XSSFFont font = workbook.createFont();
            font.setColor(HSSFColor.WHITE.index);
            XSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
            style.setFont(font);
            style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
            style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.RED.index);


            String[] header = { "name","surname"};
            XSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((short) 0);
            XSSFCell cell;
            int cellnum = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < header.length; i++) {
                cell = rowhead.createCell(cellnum);
                cell.setCellValue(header[i]);
                cell.setCellStyle(style);
                cell.setCellType(XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                cellnum++;
            }

            if (data) {
                int myRowData = 1;
                XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) myRowData);
                ArrayList<GasNomination> list = this.select();

                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

                    row.createCell(0).setCellValue(list.get(i).name());
                    row.createCell(1).setCellValue(list.get(i).surname());

                    myRowData++;
                    row = sheet.createRow((short) myRowData);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
```

I tried cell.setCellType(XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
But when I open my Excel I see formatcell type numeric ...

Comment: hi, are you using apache-poi for this?

Comment: org.apache.poi ,  poi-ooxml , <version>3.15 . XSSFWorkbook

Comment: ok, To format the contents of a cell, you first need to know what kind of cell it is, then you can use a switch case on the cell's type: e.g:  `switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                case CellType.STRING://format code here// case CellType.NUMERIC: format code here ` Basically use a cellStyle, set the required formatting into that cellStyle using and apply that format to the required cell(s). Alternatively, you can also use: `DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();  String text = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DataFormatter,

```
    System.out.println("started");

    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
    XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
    XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0);

    cell.setCellValue(3.14159);
    cell.setCellType(XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);

    XSSFDataFormat format = workbook.createDataFormat();
    XSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
    style.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("Text"));

    cell.setCellStyle(style);

    workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("Test.xlsx"));

    System.out.println("finished");
```

Comment: First Cell is text but, 15 rows are numeric.

Comment: if you want to format complete column then you can use this line, sheet.getColumnStyle(1).setDataFormat(format.getFormat("Text"));

Comment: thanks, now I have other problems, when my user add new row al excell , default this line is numeric ...